# Displaying Spotify album cover web page

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, spotify

I have an ASP.NET Website where the users could search for albums or artists on Spotify. The search results need to display the album/artists and their related artwork like the album cover.

This does not look to be possible using Spotify's Web API, as discussed [here][1]

Is this possible using the LibSpotify API? or is there any other way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, libspotify allows you to get cover art for albums and artists (although a lot of artists don't have images). Once you have an image, you can pass it to your application for display on the web.

Comment: do you know if there are any issues with using libspotify for a website?  it looks as though it is intended be used within a non-web based application like a desktop app.

Comment: That's correct. However, as long as you're not breaking the TOS you should be fine. The main one to look out for is that you can't log in "on behalf" of the user - i.e., save their details and do stuff to their account when they're not using your app.

If you have your own account to log into libspotify with and do image lookups, that should be fine as long as you identify that the images came from Spotify on your web app.

Comment: D you know if the image I get from libspotify is a URL to an image or does it return the bytes that make up an image and i then would have to generate the image file myself?
alternatively, i was thinking maybe i could call the Last Fm api using the artists name i get from spotify and use the image from there.  what do you think?